# laravel 8 call to undefined method upsert

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I just upgraded laravel to v8, I am trying to run the upsert function documented [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries) on a seeder.

Here is a code sample of what I am running

```php
namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class NewspaperSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeders.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table("newspapers")->upsert(
                       ["rows to insert"], 
                       ["primary key"], 
                       ["attributes to update if duplicate"]);
    }
}
```

Meanwhile, I end up getting this error when I run `php artisan db:seed`

```
 BadMethodCallException

  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::upsert()

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php:50
     46▕      * @throws \BadMethodCallException
     47▕      */
     48▕     protected static function throwBadMethodCallException($method)
     49▕     {
  ➜  50▕         throw new BadMethodCallException(sprintf(
     51▕             'Call to undefined method %s::%s()', static::class, $method
     52▕         ));
     53▕     }
     54▕ }

  • Bad Method Call: Did you mean Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::insert() ?
```

#### Edit (composer.json):

I followed Upgrading Guide on the official documentation, run `composer update`

```json
{
  "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5",
        "ext-json": "^7.4",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.10",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.0",
        "laravel/legacy-factories": "^1.0",
        "laravel/passport": "^10.0",
        "laravel/socialite": "^5.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "laravel/ui": "^3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "facade/ignition": "^2.3.6",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.0"
    },
}
```

Comment: yes, search for upsert on the documentation I linked and you will find it

Comment: The upsert method will insert rows that do not exist and update the rows that already exist with the new values. The method's first argument is the values to insert or update, while the second argument is the column(s) that uniquely identify records within the associated table. The method's third and final argument is the columns that should be updated if a matching record already exists in the database:

Comment: you will have to wait for the next tagged release of `laravel/framework` to use that feature

Comment: I had the same with Laravel 8.9.0: `BadMethodCallException`
`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::upsert()`

Comment: @PaulH Laravel 8.10 is now released, upgrade your version to it and it should work now. check https://github.com/laravel/framework/releases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to wait for the next tagged release of Laravel 8.x. Currently we are on `8.9.0` which does **not** include this change yet.

This is an error on the part of the people managing the framework for adding this to the 8.x docs before it is actually in a release for 8.x.

After it is tagged and released you will have to update your dependency on the framework, `laravel/framework`, to use that method.

```
 composer update laravel/framework
```

Or update all deps

```
composer update
```

Comment: I did, I followed the Upgrade Guide and updated versions and dependencies, I will add part of my composer.json to the question.

Comment: @HamzaMogni you can't use that yet, it is not in any currently tagged version, you will have to wait for the next release

Comment: ah, so the problem is in including it on the docs before release. Thanks for your assistance?